# Cannot assign proper float values to class members in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I've got strange problem with my constructor. I wrote **class "Training"** which represents some measured parameters. 5 out of 8 members are initialized directly, whereas rest need to perform simple calculations before value will be assigned to them. My problem is that these 3 float variables contains 0 after object is created. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
public class Training {
    int hr1;            
    int hr2;            
    int hr3;            
    int hr4;
    String date;    

    float wsr;                                               //problem
    float hrDec1;                                            //problem
    float hrDec5;                                            //problem



public Training(int hr1, int hr2, int hr3, int hr4, String date) {
    this.hr1 = hr1;
    this.hr2 = hr2;
    this.hr3 = hr3;
    this.hr4 = hr4;
    this.date = date;

    this.wsr =    ( (hr2 - hr4) / (hr2 - hr1) ) * 100.0f;   //problem
    this.hrDec1 = ( (hr2 - hr3) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;           //problem
    this.hrDec5 = ( (hr2 - hr4) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;           //problem

}

public String toString(){
    return date+" | WSR: "+wsr +", HRdec1: "+hrDec1 +", HRdec5: "+ hrDec5;
}
```

}

After printing new object ex.

```
Training t = new Training(90, 190, 130, 110, "15.08.2015"); 
System.out.println(t);
```

I will receive:

```
15.08.2015 | WSR: 0.0, HRdec1: 0.0, HRdec5: 0.0
```

float values contain 0 - why?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation for the float values uses integer values `hr1`, `hr2`, `hr3` and `hr4`. In Java the result of an integer division is also an integer.

So if you do a divison that results in a number that is not an integer, java rounds it down.

In your case the calculation is rounded down to zero first, because it is an integer division, both the dividend and divisor are integers.

To enforce float divison it is enough to turn one of the values to a float, for example by mutiplying it with a float (100.0f in this case):

```
this.wsr = ((hr2 - hr4) * 100.0f)/ (hr2 - hr1);   
this.hrDec1 = ((hr2 - hr3) * 100.0f) / hr2;           
this.hrDec5 = ((hr2 - hr4) * 100.0f) / hr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing INTEGER division. Try this to convert the integers to doubles before doing the division:

```
 this.wsr =    ( (hr2 - hr4) / ((hr2 - hr1) * 1.0) ) * 100.0f;   
 this.hrDec1 = ( (hr2 - hr3) / (hr2 * 1.0) ) * 100.0f;          
 this.hrDec5 = ( (hr2 - hr4) / (hr2 * 1.0) ) * 100.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `int a/int b` and then multiplying the result by `100.0f`. If `b > a` then `a/b` (integer division) returns zero. So multiplying `100.0f` later does not give you what you are expecting. You should multiply it before division.

change

```
this.wsr =    ( (hr2 - hr4) / (hr2 - hr1) ) * 100.0f;   //problem
this.hrDec1 = ( (hr2 - hr3) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;           //problem
this.hrDec5 = ( (hr2 - hr4) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;
```

to

```
this.wsr =    ( (hr2 - hr4)*100.0f)/ (hr2 - hr1) ;   
this.hrDec1 = ( (hr2 - hr3)*100.0f) / hr2;           
this.hrDec5 = ( (hr2 - hr4)*100.0f) / hr2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following in your code:

```
this.wsr =    ( (float)(hr2 - hr4) / (hr2 - hr1) ) * 100.0f;   
this.hrDec1 = ( (float)(hr2 - hr3) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;           
this.hrDec5 = ( (float)(hr2 - hr4) / hr2 ) * 100.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've tried, unfortunately without expected result.
EDIT: My bad, I was casting in bad bracket, your solution also works, Thank you! :)